# remove css class on change, irrespective of the value in the select field using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the below select filed populating values from mysqlDB. By default i am hiding the next two read only fields. I need to show the hided 2 fields when the value changes in the select field(irrespective of the value).
I am not familiar with java script, i have tried with one script, but it is not working.
Please support.

```
<select id ="name" name="name" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Wallet</option>

    <?php
    //my query       
    echo '<option value="' . $row['group'] . '">' . $row['group'] . '</option>';//qry output to the select field

    ?>

</select>
<div  id ="hide" class="form-group hide">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
        <input id ="od" value="<?php echo $od ?>" class="form-control" readonly/>
        <input id="bal" value="<?php echo $bal ?>" class="form-control" readonly/>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#name").change(function () {
$("#hide").removeClass('hide');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
<select id ="name" name="name" class="form-control" required onChange="showTextBox()">
```

and add this function

```
function showTextBox(){
    $("#hide").removeClass('hide');
}
```

**OR**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name").change(function () {
        $("#hide").removeClass('hide');
    });
})
```

;

Answer (score 1):

**.show()** and **.hide()** method to  hide and and show particular elements as per their name suggests

and you can use the " on " event so that it can work on even you dynamically add the options to the select tag by using jquery or javascript.

```js
// or want to use by adding and removing class so you can use as below.
 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name").on('change',(function () {
        $("#hide").removeClass('hide');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#name").change(function () {
      $("#hide").removeClass('hide');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, its not working. I have applied the above provided script, still on changing the value in the select field, the next two fields are not displaying.

Comment: Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$(".hide").show();` instead of `$("#hide").removeClass('hide');`